# Iterating through a JS object not giving the correct data and the time needed for bootstrap popover?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

I have a map with several hover points which I am using Bootstrap popover to display info about. Like this:http://benmartinek.com/gisela/asia.html (hover over Singapore). The issue is that you cannot add links the popovers unless it is done programmatically in JS.

So I started to write all the information in an object:

```
locationHash = {
    "singapore": ["Singapore", "some text 1", '<a href="http://travel.nytimes.com/2012/01/22/travel/hawker-food-courts-in-singapore.html?pagewanted=all"Link</a>'],
    "skorea": ["Seoul", "some text 2", '<a href="http://travel.nytimes.com/2012/01/22/travel/hawker-food-courts-in-singapore.html?pagewanted=all"Link</a> '],

    }
```

No problem here accept when I try to access it. When hovering over South Korea, I am still getting "Singapore" for the title. Here is the code for that:

```
$('.locations').each(function(i) {
    locationId = $('.locations')[i].id;
    locationTitle = ('' + locationHash[locationId][0]);

    $("[rel=popover]").popover({
        animation: true,
        html: true,
        trigger: 'hover',
        offset: 10,
        title:  locationTitle,
        placement: 'right',
        delay: {
            show: 200,
            hide: 1500
        }
    });

});
```

Is this because the popover is not generated yet? Suggestions on a better strategy for this?

Comment: There's an error in your locationHash object: 'all"Link</a>' should be 'all">Link</a>' (missing a > bracket)

Comment: You also don't need the `'' +` part when you create the locationTitle - it's already a string so you don't need to coerce it.

Comment: `locationId = ...` line can be reduced to:

`locationId = $(this).id;` - you don't need to use the index to look up the current element. You might consider setting the location as a data attribute just to be safer that someone does't change it and break it. `data-location="singapore"`, then use `locationId = $(this).data("location");`

Answer (score 1):

Try this, `$("[rel=popover]")` will select all `rel=popover` and give the same `locationTitle` to all of them so you must use this and find the `rel=popover`

```
   $(this).find("[rel=popover]").popover({
```

Comment: I still get an error trying to access the [0] element in: `locationTitle = ('' + locationHash[locationId][0]);`

Comment: Try changing  `locationId = $('.locations')[i].id;` to `locationId = this.id` @bmartinek

Comment: Thanks Anton, I tried that with no avail. In the Chrome console I can use `locationHash.singapore[0]` to get "Singapore", but it gives me this error when the page loads: `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined tip_style.js:22
(anonymous function) tip_style.js:22
x.extend.each jquery.js:4
x.fn.x.each jquery.js:4
(anonymous function)`